# Run Grunt tasks during Bluemix deployment

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, ibm-cloud

I have an exciting Node app which I'd like to migrate from being hosted on Heroku to Bluemix. It's a little complicated in that the deploy runs various tasks, kicked off by a section of my `package.js` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
  "postinstall": "grunt heroku"
},
```

The grunt task kicks off dependent talks found in my `Gruntfile.js` file, like pulling in Bower packages, minifying images, browserify, moving, files, cleaning, etc.

I assume I can kick off deploy tasks when pushing to Bluemix?  If so, would they just be done in a similar fashion (commands in scripts section of `package.json`) to run tasks defined in my `Gruntfile.js`?

In heroku, my entire git repo would be replicated to their remote, so everything was there, not just the output of running scripts to product a dist directory, I assume that would be the same on Bluemix?

Last, in my package file, I would define npm and node versions:

```
"engines": {
  "npm": "2.5.1",
  "node": "0.12.0"
}
```

and Heroku would ensure that it's running that version specific to my instance.  Is it the same for Bluemix?

Thank you very much!
Paul

Comment: Thanks Dan for deciphering what I was trying to say and putting it in an easier to read fashion :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Bluemix, the `npm install` command is run to install your dependencies.  This will kick-off your `grunt heroku` task in the `postinstall` section.  Note that your `devDependencies` will not be downloaded. In case your grunt task requires them, they may need to be moved to the `dependencies` section.

Right, your entire application repository that you have pushed will be replicated on Bluemix, similar to Heroku.

You can now specify the Node and NPM engine, as you have it in your `package.json`.

**Outdated:**
*You can certainly specify the node engine, just like you have it in your example.  However, the NPM version is currently not configurable, and is instead provided by what is packaged within that Node.js runtime.*

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking to know.  My app works perfectly in Heroku with the heroku task in my grunt tasks, glad to hear that things will be about the same in Bluemix.   Thank you so much for confirming that!:)  Do you know if I can just push to a git remote endpoint similar to Heroku?  I assume I just login with the cf tool and should be able to push to a bluemix remote (which i'd define).

Comment: Pushing and creating repositories for Bluemix applications isn't integrated with the "cf" tool.  Instead, you have a couple of different options for hosting your code on a Git repo for Bluemix:
1) Navigate to your application on the Bluemix dashboard and hit "Add Git"
2) Directly create a code repository on "[hub.jazz.net](http://hub.jazz.net)".

Once you've created this git repository on IBM DevOps Services, you can either use their WebIDE to edit your code, or directly push to the git repository provided.  You can also customize the automated build and deploy to Bluemix!